# What goes into .env file?

Tags: refactoring, environment

Working on a huge application with lots of legacy code, I often encounter environment "checks":

```
db_name = Rails.env.production? ? 'staging_db' : 'production_db'
...
desired_processes_count = Rails.env.production? ? 6 : 1
...
Rails.env.production? ? "index,follow" : "noindex,nofollow"
```

and so on. It's Ruby on Rails, but I guess the question is applicable for a wider range of projects, despite the technology.

The app does use `.dotenv`, and in the `.env` file, there are:

- credentials
- hostnames
- secrets

and that's about it.

In my opinion, readability increases significantly if all of the aforementioned examples:

- DATABASE_NAME
- PROCESSES_COUNT (not really readable though, could be more descriptive)
- SEARCH_ENGINES_INDEXING_DIRECTIVE

are stored as environment variables - it does not have to be `.env`, obviously, just a single configuration file with all of them.

I am not an expert though.

**How can I evaluate if the variable qualifies as an environment variable?**

Is there any rule of thumb, set of best practices? Or is it a completely opinion-based question?

Answer (score 1):

That is a question of configuration.

Is this aspect of your application requiring information not available at compile time in order to function?

If so expose it through several mechanisms:

- A Configuration File
- Environment Variables
- Command line arguments
- Interactive Configuration

Which and how much of what is a matter of taste and utility. Generally a configuration file is sufficient with a command line/environment variable pointing to it. Secrets might make more sense stored as environment variables, but again a mater of taste.

If an option is going to be available via multiple interfaces ensuring a common name or addressing style is crucial to avoid confusion.

Similarly if an option can be specified via multiple methods, ensure that those means have a clear order of applicability so that if it is specified several times, only one is considered correct (or an immediate validation error occurs). eg: From least to most relevant: `General Config File > Config File Specified by Environment Variable > Environment Variable > Config File specified by Command Line Argument > Command Line Argument > Interactive Response.`

Ensure that your application accesses the configuration via a consistent internal mechanism, if you only happens to use environment variables that is fine. Still I would isolate the how from the what to allow for future differences in both what and how.